# react (next) wait context data and passing values to custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-context

I am trying to consume data from context, into a custom hook. the problem is that the data is not ready and the hook takes the default values.
How can I make my custom hook take the updated values ​​once the context is ready?

**timer context**

> the context expects two values ​​that I get from the database

```
//context
export const TimerContext = createContext();

//hook
export const useTimer = () => useContext(TimerContext);

//provider
export const TimerProvider = ({ children }) => {
  //estado del context
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState({
    inicioPartido: "Apr 8, 2022 01:00:00",
    finPartido: "Apr 8, 2022 01:10:00",
  });

  return (
    <TimerContext.Provider value={{ timer, setTimer }}>
      {children}
    </TimerContext.Provider>
  );


};
```

**page index.js**

> timers it is an object that I get from the database, here everything works fine
> the object exists and is stored in the context

```
const {timer, setTimer } = useTimer();

 useEffect(() => {
    setTimer({
      inicioPartido: timers.start_timer,
      finPartido: timers.end_timer,
    });
  }, [timers]);
```

**the issue**

> when I pass both dates to my custom hook, it gets only the default values ​​that I put in the context

```
const { inicio, termino, segundo, minuto, hora, dia } = useCounterhook(
   timer.inicioPartido,
   timer.finPartido
 );
```

**instead**

> If I send the dates hard coded everything works perfectly

```
const { inicio, termino, segundo, minuto, hora, dia } = useCounterhook(
   "Apr 8, 2022 03:40:00",
   "Apr 8, 2022 03:50:00"
 );
```

**MY CUSTOM HOOK**

> my hook compares the distance between two dates and generates a countdown

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";


const useCounterhook = (fechaInicio, fechaTermino) => {
  //states
  const [segundo, setSegundo] = useState(0);
  const [minuto, setMinuto] = useState(0);
  const [hora, setHora] = useState(0);
  const [dia, setDia] = useState(0);
  const [inicio, setInicio] = useState(false);
  const [termino, setTermino] = useState(false);

  //real time settings
  const second = 1000;
  const minute = second * 60;
  const hour = minute * 60;
  const day = hour * 24;

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      let inicio = new Date(fechaInicio).getTime();
      let termino = new Date(fechaTermino).getTime();
      let ahora = new Date().getTime();
      let distance = inicio - ahora;

      if (inicio > ahora && termino > ahora) {
        //si fechaInicio es mayor a este instante
        //partido aun no inicia
        setDia(Math.floor(distance / day));
        setHora(Math.floor((distance % day) / hour));
        setMinuto(Math.floor((distance % hour) / minute));
        setSegundo(Math.floor((distance % minute) / second));
        setInicio(false);
        setTermino(false);
      }
      if (inicio < ahora && termino > ahora) {
        //si fecha inicio es menor a este instante
        // partido ya inicio y aun no termina
        setDia(0);
        setHora(0);
        setMinuto(0);
        setSegundo(0);
        setInicio(true);
        setTermino(false);
      }
      if (inicio < ahora && termino < ahora) {
        //si fecha inicio es mayor a fecha de termino
        //el partido ya termino
        setDia(0);
        setHora(0);
        setMinuto(0);
        setSegundo(0);
        setInicio(false);
        setTermino(true);
      }
    }, 1000);

   
  }, []);

  return { inicio, termino, segundo, minuto, hora, dia };
};

export default useCounterhook;


useCounterhook.propTypes = {
  fechaInicio: PropTypes.string,
  fechaTermino: PropTypes.string,
};
```

**I think it is because the context is not ready, when the hook is already waiting for the values, but I don't know how to solve it**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `useCounterHook` is running the `useEffect` based on the first time it is mounted and then never accounts for when the `timer` values change.

If you make use of the `useEffect` dependency array you can resolve this.

Update the `useEffect` in your `useCounterHook` to the following and you should be good to go:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      // this content doesn't change
    }, 1000);

    // useEffect's cleanup method
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
    
    // dependency array to listen if `fetchaInicio` or `fetchTermino` changes
  }, [fechaInicio, fechaTermino]);
```

Now your hook will check if either of those inputs change and if that is the case the timer will stop and then start a new timer with the new values.